# Multithreaded OpenSSL

Tags: c++, multithreading, openssl, libcurl

I am using libcurl with OpenSSL in a multithreaded-program. Based on the kind response from Daniel Stenberg and the examples

- [opensslthreadlock.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/opensslthreadlock.html)
- [threaded-ssl.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threaded-ssl.html)

I tried the following code:

```
static std::mutex* aMutex;

void locking_function(int mode, int n, const char* file, int line)
{
    if(mode & CRYPTO_LOCK){
        std::cout << "Mutex locking\n";
        aMutex[n].lock();
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Mutex unlocking\n";
        aMutex[n].unlock();
    }
}

unsigned long id_function()
{
    return (unsigned long)std::hash<std::thread::id>()   (std::this_thread::get_id());
}

int thread_setup()
{
    aMutex = new std::mutex[CRYPTO_num_locks()];
    if(!aMutex)
        return 0;
    else{
        CRYPTO_set_id_callback(id_function);
        CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(locking_function);
    }
    return 1;
}

int thread_cleanup()
{
    if(!aMutex)
        return 0;

    CRYPTO_set_id_callback(NULL);
    CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(NULL);
    delete[] aMutex;
    aMutex = NULL;
    return 1;
}
```

So I provide the locking function, the thread-identifier function and let the locking_function use a global array of mutexes.

The sentences "Mutex locking" and "Mutex unlocking" (which are printed in the locking_function) gets printed over and over really fast. When I destroy the CURL handle it stops. Is this normal/correct?

I call

```
thread_setup
```

when my application starts and

```
thread_cleanup
```

when the application ends.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The sentences "Mutex locking" and "Mutex unlocking" (which are printed in the locking_function) gets printed over and over really fast.
```

Mutex lock/unlock are used to ensure only one thread accesses the critical section at one time (that's why it's called mutual exclusion). In a multi-threaded program, where you use an array of mutexes and use the same methods for locking/unlocking them, these two I expect would get called many times. Plus the execution of the critical section is usually fast(a few lines of code).

So to give you a straight answer, yes, what you are seeing is normal

Comment: Thank you! I have a decent grasp on mutexes and multi-threading in general, but very little experience with OpenSSL and libcurl, so did not really know what behavior to expect from OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that on some platforms this code could have an error:

```
(unsigned long)std::hash<std::thread::id>()   (std::this_thread::get_id());
```

`std::hash()` returns `size_t` and you cast it to `unsigned long`. On Win-64 platform, `size_t` is 64 bit and `unsigned long` is 32 bit.

Comment: Even more -- std::hassh does not guarantee absence of collisions -- it may return the same value for two different `thread_id` values potentially causing UB.